# terminal still showing python version 3.5 even though 3.9 was installed

Tags: python, macos, installation, python-3.5, python-3.9

I downloaded and installed Python 3.9 using the Original Installer from python.org, and also tried it with Homebrew after that, which also installed 3.9. However, `python3 --version` still tells me I have 3.5.1?

My work computer does not have this issue, so something seems to be pointing the wrong way on my personal machine. 3.5 has reached the end of its life, as Python keeps telling me, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: your system may have multiple python distributions. use `which python3` to see which version it's pointing to.  Find where 3.9 was installed and call it by path

Comment: I would open the terminal again for the paths to be reloaded. If that doesn't work set the path yourself as export PATH = <path to python3.9>:$PATH, you should place this in your bash profile for future usage.

Comment: You should run `which python3.9` in the terminal. If you see text `/usr/bin/python3.9`, then it's successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to just restart the terminal but `which python3` still pointed to 3.5. After changing the PATH with `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` and then also restarting the terminal it worked.